# OpenCV modify image pixels

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to modify each pixel of an image. But the result is not like I expected.

Original image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

For loop to modify each pixel:

```
image = imread("image.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
unsigned char value;

for (int col = 0; col < image.cols; col++){
   for (int row = 0; row < image.rows; row++){
        value = image.at<unsigned char>(row,col);
        value *= 0;
        image.at<unsigned char>(row, col) = value;
   }
}
```

So I don't know where the mistake is and I want to ask you if you know the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a 3 channel unsigned char image, you need to access all 3 channels using `Vec3b` as you loop through rows and cols.

```
image = imread("image.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
Vec3b value;

for (int row = 0; row < image.rows; row++){
   for (int col = 0; col < image.cols; col++){
        //Vec3b as typename
        value = image.at<Vec3b>(row,col);
        value *= 0;
        image.at<Vec3b>(row, col) = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Since the same operation is done on all the pixels, I'd prefer a matrix expression -- faster and more concise. | Considering OP is multiplying by 0, a simple `setTo` or even just a scalar assignment would do.

Comment: @DanMašek Yes, there are many other ways (e.g matrix multiplication, bitwise operations, parallel_for etc) to perform this operation. But, since the OP seems to be a beginner in CV and is interested in accessing each pixel, I gave my answer accordingly.